# Proof about power series without using the continuity property

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, power-series

[image: The question]

[image: What I've done]

I took a picture of what I've tried to do and the proof I'm asking to provide. I feel like the hint just made me doubt what I would have done intuitively. What do we use abs(a(n)).

Answer (score 2):

$$
\left | \sum_n a_nx^n\right|\\
\stackrel{\text{triangle ineq.}}{\leq}
\sum_n |a_n||x|^n\\
\stackrel{|x|\leq K}{\leq}\sum_n |a_n|K^n\\
\stackrel{K<R}{<}+\infty
$$
Where the final inequality is true because power series converge absolutely (and uniformly) on compact subsets of the interval of convergence (see @David C. Ullrich's proof above). So $|f(x)|$ for $x\in [-K,K]$ is indeed bounded, specifically by 
$\sum_n |a_n|K^n$.

Comment: But why is $\sum|a_n|K^n$ finite?

Comment: I thought this was obvious from the definition of radius of convergence, am I missing something?

Comment: Well  it's not hard, but the usual definition is just that $\sum a_n x^n$ _converges_ for $|x|<R$, doesn't say anything a priori about absolute conergence...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I see your point; I will edit the above. I have always thought of the radius as arising from either the ratio or Hadamard's test, which implies absolute convergence.

Comment: Imo that's sad, like when students get the idea that $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ is the _definition_ of "eigenvalue"...

Answer (score 1):

The point is to show that $\sum|a_n|K^n<\infty$; once you know that you're done because...

Hint: Say $K<x<R$. Then the series $\sum a_nx^n$ converges, so the terms are bounded; say $$|a_nx^n|\le c.$$

But $$|a_n|K^n=\left(\frac Kx\right)^n|a_nx^n|,$$so...